# Rails simplify a query to get user profile's first_name

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, model-associations

I want to retrieve application.applicant.profile.first_name for the applicant and I'm not able to retrieve the profile attribute:first_name using applicant above.

Profile, application are connected by foreign key: user_id to user.Can someone suggest a way?

Here are my associations:

user.rb

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
 has_many :applications
 has_one :profile, -> { where role: 'user' }, dependent: :destroy
```

profile.rb

```
class Profile < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :user, :class_name => 'User', :foreign_key => 'user_id'
```

job.rb

```
class Job < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :applications, :dependent => :destroy
    has_many :applicants, :through => :applications, :class_name => 'User'
```

application.rb

```
class Application < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :job
  belongs_to :applicant, :class_name => 'User', :foreign_key => 'user_id'
```

Answer (score 0):

This line isn't correct...

```
 has_one :profile, -> { where role: 'user' }, class_name: 'User', dependent: :destroy
```

It should be...

```
 has_one :profile, -> { where role: 'user' }, dependent: :destroy
```

The class_name for `:profile` is `Profile` but you don't need to specify it as it can be derived from the symbol by rails.

Comment: Cool, so has that fixed your problem?

Comment: I gave my answer below. Your update was just an error I made while typing.

Answer (score 0):

After numerous permutations and combinations such as polymorphic, select & join statement or even by providing a SQL query, finally realised that it was as simple as a single statement as I knew the user_id of current user:

```
<% post.applications.each do |papplication| %>
  <%= Profile.find_by_user_id(papplication.user_id).first_name %> <% end %>
```